# Slider on Javascript is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

Simple JS Slider is running ONLY to the 2nd slide image, and it's not continue running. I am using vue.js and tried to apply js code there, no errors, just not continue running.

1.Call one function inside another one(works until 2nd slide)

2.Function inside function(works until 2nd slide)

3.Combine two functions in one(crush)

My Code:

```
 slider: function() {
        var slides = document.querySelectorAll('#slides .slide');
        var currentSlide = 0;
        slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide';
        currentSlide = (currentSlide + 1) % slides.length;
        slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide showing';
    },

    nextSlide: function(){
            var slideInterval = setInterval(app.slider, 2000);
    }
},
```

Then I go app.slider() or app.NextSlide(). Running until 2nd slide all the time(or crush with undefined)

Just make it run to the 5th slide and then start from the first one as expected.

---

*Source code of an example that I am trying to apply: https://webformyself.com/kak-sdelat-prostoj-slajder-na-javascript-bez-jquery/ (Russian guide)*

Comment: Note that you set `currentSlide` to `0` every time `slider` is called. And if you manipulate DOM in vue, you're propably doing it wrong

Comment: Thanks it's working properly now